# Login callback fails w/500, how to debug reason

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, .net-core-2.2

We have an application running in four environments where 3 out of 4 are working as expected.  We don't think code changes are required but instead some type of configuration in either the Azure environment, B2C setup or the application is causing the problem.  After looking at this very closely, we see that the callback to /signon-oidc receives a 302 Not found but the location is set to the application error handler.  snippet of fiddler response to signin-oidc shown below. the location in other environments is the fully qualified application url of the app.  How is this location determined from B2C?

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

**Location: /Home/Error**

What options are available to increase the logging information for this type of failure?  The redirect callback incorrectly sets the location for redirect.  But how and where is this determined?

startup.cs - ConfigureServices

```
       services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddAzureAd(options =>
       {
           Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
           options.ContentEditorClientKey = Configuration["AzureAd:WebPortalAzureAdKey"];
           ....
           AzureAdOptions.Settings = options;
       })
       .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind($"ContentEditor{nameof(AzureAdB2COptions)}", options))
       .AddCookie(options =>
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookiedomain))
               options.Cookie.Domain = cookiedomain;
       });
```

startup.cs - Configure

```
        ....
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        ....
```

Fiddler

[image]

Fiddler - xml response snippet from B2C login to /signin-oidc
[image]

Fiddler - signin-oidc response has **WRONG** location

[image]

App Error displayed

[image]

We've looked pretty carefully at the redirect URL, cookies, WAF environment, etc., but cannot determine why the location in the signin-oidc is set to the wrong value. What additional logging can I place in B2C and/or the web application (.Net core 2.2)? Or, how is the location value set?

Comment: Hi @user2503078. If the authentication middleware has failed to handle the authentication response from Azure AD B2C, then the ASP.NET Core logs should contain an exception message. Any unhandled exception will redirect to `/Home/Error`.

Comment: What is in the “web forms” of Frame 4 Request?

Comment: @JasSuri, there is no web forms property shown in the request of the /signin-oidc.

Comment: What is in the XML response of Frame 3? Do you see the tokens there? It should be doing a hidden Form POST to your App in Frame 4.

Comment: hi @JasSuri, i added what I think your looking for in the original post, see "Fiddler - xml response to signin-oidc".  The form action value looks correct.  Is there something else in the XML that I should be looking at?